# How to use secured queries in Apache Jena 3.10.0?

Tags: sparql, jena

I am trying to build secured query in Apache Jena v.3.10.0.
I want to pass some query, modify the query according to existing SecurityEvaluator and execute it later.

However, I don't understand how it should be used with certain format of queries.

I tried doing it using simplified version of SecuredQueryEngine.

```
public class GenSecuredEngine extends QueryEngineMain {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SecuredQueryEngine.class);

    private SecurityEvaluator securityEvaluator;
    private Node graphIRI;

    public GenSecuredEngine(final Query query, final DatasetGraph dataset,
                            final  SecurityEvaluator evaluator,
                            final Binding input, final Context context) {
        super(query, dataset, input, context);
        this.securityEvaluator = evaluator;
        graphIRI = NodeFactory.createURI("urn:x-arq:DefaultGraph");
    }


    @Override
    protected Op modifyOp(final Op op) {
        final OpRewriter rewriter = new OpRewriter(securityEvaluator, graphIRI);
        LOG.debug("Before: {}", op);
        op.visit(rewriter);
        Op result = rewriter.getResult();
        result = result == null ? op : result;
        LOG.debug("After: {}", result);
        result = super.modifyOp(result);
        LOG.debug("After Optimize: {}", result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then we have such code modifying the given query into Op, checking the permissions and building the new Op object.

```
Op oporiginal = new AlgebraGenerator().compile(query);
Op result = securedEngine.modifyOp(oporiginal);
System.out.println(OpAsQuery.asQuery(result));
```

If I pass the query like this

```
select *
where {
  graph <forbiddenGraphUri> {?a ?b ?c}
}
```

then everything works fine and the "forbiddenUri" is checked against SecurityEvaluator and throws org.apache.jena.shared.ReadDeniedException: Model permissions violation.

But what if user wants to execute something like this:

```
select * where { graph ?g {?a ?b ?c}}
```

In this case we can check only URI of "?g" which is not really informative. I understand that AlgebraGenerator does not fill the missing spots so this is probably the wrong approach.
So, how can it be done? For example, if user wants to run the query against many named graphs, how to filter the not allowed ones? Is it possible at all with the existing tools?

Comment: This is a quite detailed question. You may need to ask on the Jena users list : users@jena.apache.org (subscribe first).

Comment: @AndyS I read more over the weekend and realized that using SPARQL algebra is quite wrong approach and since the SecuredEngine uses it I cannot really get things done this way. So instead I just run the query over the dataset which contains only allowed graphs. This seems like more simple approach, I will probably post it as answer.

Comment: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/data-access-control might help. It is graph-level access control. One important class is org.apache.jena.fuseki.access.DatasetGraphAccessControl

Comment: Thanks, it is interesting read and seems to be a new feature, but it has some limitations such as "Graph level access control only applies to read-only datasets." And also it looks like SecurityRegistry can be defined only as Strings, which makes the access permissions hard to add or modify (currently I store ACL in separate dataset). So it would put some restrictions on my current design :(

Comment: The security registry can be a different implementation - the one in the codebase is standalone; Obv. there is a need to hook into the environment SSO (LDAP etc). The "readonly" at the graph level is because there isn't a mechanism to manage updates. The interesting case being creating new graphs. In the system that motivated it, updates are via service-control; the mechanism can be mixed.